# how to parse DB field into gridview asp:TemplateField

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, gridview

I have a DB record with field `JsonPreview`

formatted: `{Name:"bla bla", ImageUrl:"www.myimago.gif"}`

I want to split this data into two columns in my gridView table

How can I do this?

```
<asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Name">
<ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Image ID="ItemImage" runat="server" ImageUrl="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, JsonPreview.ImageUrl)) %>" />
</ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: why not split them in code behind ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split them into two fields in your code behind as

```
// Let I have two properties on my page as
 protected string ImageUrl { get; set; }
protected string Name { get; set; }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Suppose I have the value in a string variable val
   string val = " {Name:'bla bla', ImageUrl:'www.myimago.gif'}";

   // Split them using String.Split function
   string[] array = val.Split(',');
   ImageUrl = array[1].Replace('}',' ');
   Name = array[0].Replace('{',' ');   

}

// aspx source code

<%= Name %>        // Output: Name:'bla bla' 
<%= ImageUrl %>    // Output: ImageUrl:'www.myimago.gif'
```

Or if you want only ImageURL then you can return only ImageURL from your sql query as

```
Declare @var varchar(50)
set @var = '{Name:"bla bla", ImageUrl:"www.myimago.gif"}'

select SUBSTRING(@var, CHARINDEX('ImageUrl:',@var,0) ,LEN(@var) - CHARINDEX('ImageUrl:',@var,0)) as [Image URL]

// Output: ImageUrl:"www.myimago.gif"
```

Comment: there is no page_load event in mvc.

Comment: @SMK beta the user has also tagged Asp.Net :P